# How to add a comma in the loop result in cypress java script

Tags: javascript, cypress

```
cy.xpath(ListOfElements).then(contents => {
const headerColumnTxt =contents.text() 
cy.log("header columns: "+ headerColumnTxt)
```

The output result coming like : `OneTwoThreeFour`.
I need it as like : `"One","Two","Three","Four"`

Comment: Is there any suggestion for it

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function doing this. With a little adaption it should do what you want:

```
getAllElementsInString(alias: string) {
    const getElemLabls = ($labels) => {
      // eslint-disable-next-line
      const attrs = [...$labels].map((h) => h.textContent);
      return attrs.join('","');
    };
    cy.get(ListOfElements)
      .then(getElemLabls)
      .then((elemstr) => {
        const txt = '"'${elemstr}; // then you still have to remove the ," at the end
      });
  }
```